# Assign value to a specific textbox in the php file just before it is created

Tags: php, joomla, textbox, contact-form

I have a contact form module on joomla that allows me to add different kinds of fields. i.e. textboxes, radio button, check boxes. The module allows me to specify default values for the fields on the back end. But what i want is to take the heading of the page,

```
<div class="componentheading">
<h1>Page Name</h1>
</div>
```

`Page Name` and assign it to one of the textboxes just before the contact form loads. If that's asking too much, I don't mind assigning the url to the textbox as long as it is SEF. I have found the php code that selects those fields from the database and creates them on the form with their default values.

```
$field->html_tag = '<input type="text" name="' . $field->name . '" id="' . $field->name . '" ' . $maxlength . ' ' . $field->field_parameters . ' value="' . $postData_field_value . '" />';
```

So, the logic would be something like this

```
if (field_name = 'WantedTextbox')
{
    $field->html_tag = '<input type="text" name="' . $field->name . '" id="' . $field->name . '" ' . $maxlength . ' ' . $field->field_parameters . ' value="' . $pageheading . '" />';
}
else
{
//The normal statement
}
```

So how do i turn this into code? I'm not that good with php.

Comment: If you're trying to track where your contact form is called from, it may be easier to simply check the HTTP_REFERER of the form submission (you could achieve this in the controller easily)

Comment: The reason i wanted the textbox to have the value of the page heading or current url is because the form will email the data entered by the user. And i want to see either the page heading or the url of the page on the email sent.